# Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: python-3.x, http, discord.py

I'm in creating a discord bot and I can't find what the following error is:

```
Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user
```

I have tried this, but with no success:

```py
if not isinstance(error, discord.HTTPException):
    await member.send(f"vous avez été bannis de {ctx.guild.name}")
    await member.ban(reason=arg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some users disable non-friend messages so you just have to skip the user or use

```py
try:
    await member.send(f"vous avez été bannis de {ctx.guild.name}")
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Empty try-except statements are not good practice. If another error occurs, it will be unknown.